# TestNG Calling to a test method from another test method

Tags: testng, call

the end of the @test in class loginAppium , i want to call another class @test
Class loginAppium

```
@Test
public void testLogin() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Login with your LabOra Id']")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='Login' and @class='android.view.View']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys("agrando.srilanka");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("embla");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btnLogin']")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='Mönsterstad pastorat']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Mönsterstad pastorat']")).click();


   addAppointment addApp = new addAppointment();
   addApp.testaddAppointment();

}
```

I want to call here

```
   @Test
public void testaddAppointment() {

    //Logout
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @width>0 and ./parent::*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[./*[@text='Logout']]]]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @width>0 and ./parent::*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[./*[@text='Logout']]]]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Yes']")).click();
```

}

But it closes the app when at following stage

```
 addAppointment addApp = new addAppointment();
 addApp.testaddAppointment();
```

Comment: seeing source of addAppointment(), testaddAppointment() could help to answer where the problem is about.

Comment: It runs the testLogin()  but then closes the app without calling to testaddAppointment()

Comment: why don't you extract testaddAppointment contains as another new method and call it at the end of testLogin()?

Comment: @SvichkarevAnatoly i have done this 
'addAppointment addApp = new addAppointment();
addApp.testaddAppointment();'
but it doesn't call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Test script development, it is not a good practice to call a test method inside a test method.

Because every test method should be **independent** of other test methods.

Because of one test method, other test method should not get pass or fail. (This obviously differs from dependsOnMethods and dependsOnGroup)
They have their own purposes.

A test method differs from a instance method or a static method.

A test method can have different-different test properties and test attribute with test data as well.

In your case :

```
 addAppointment addApp = new addAppointment();
 addApp.testaddAppointment();
```

Instead of this, try to make an instance method and call it inside a test methods.

Hope This will resolve your problem.

Let me know if you have any more concerns.

**UPDATE** :

I am wrapping this line of code. Please note that I have removed @Test annotation from this method

```
public void testaddAppointment() {

    //Logout
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @width>0 and ./parent::*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[./*[@text='Logout']]]]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @width>0 and ./parent::*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[./*[@text='Logout']]]]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Yes']")).click();
}
```

and you can call it like this :

```
  addAppointment addApp = new addAppointment();
  addApp.testaddAppointment();
```

Comment: This is so much clear but can you let me know how to call it using  instance method and call it inside a test methods ?

Comment: @user2401106 : It' been a long time, let me review this question once again.

Comment: I have been working with some other project and that's why i was not available.

Comment: @user2401106 : I have updated my answer under update section. Please verify it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to remove `@Test annotation` from another class, and call it as 
 you have define.

Another way is, you can extends destination class in base class and call that method without any `annotation dependency`.